# Git make remote master point to another branch

Tags: git

We got a 'dev' branch thats been functioning as de-facto master for quite a while.

Is there a way to make my remote/master just point to the same place as remote/dev ? (no merging / rebasing / extra work).

(More or less a rename of dev to master)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Checkout master branch, reset it to dev, push. 
This will affect users downstream who may have branches off your remote/master.

```
git checkout master

git reset --hard remote/dev

git push -f
```

This will cause you to lose any commits you have made since your remote and dev diverged, but you will end up with the same state as remote/dev.

Comment: Just to verify - I will lose all commits to master but keep all the history of the dev branch ?

Comment: This worked for me, and then I used @Roman's way to delete the old branch with `git push origin :refs/head/dev`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your remote is named `origin`,

```
git push origin +origin/dev:refs/heads/master
```

Then, if you want also to delete `dev`:

```
git push origin :refs/heads/dev
```

Comment: Presumably you'll also want to move your local master, probably with a hard reset. (At which point you might as well have just done what RJFalconer suggested.)

Comment: @Jefromi: it makes much more assumptions about the structure of the local repository. For example, it's not hard to imagine that local `master` branch simply does not exist, if there has been no activity in the upstream's `master`. In general, the mapping between local and remote branches is arbitrary, although most people indeed tend to keep it straightforward.

Comment: A valid point. I did assume that he'd have a "master" to match his "remote/master". Not a big assumption, but an assumption nevertheless.